# Getting issue while deploying spring boot war on tomcat 7

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, tomcat

I am having issue in deploying my code on the tomcat server
I have written the below code.

My main class:

```
package com.indiamart.search;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SuggestMcatApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SuggestMcatApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return builder.sources(SuggestMcatApplication.class);
    }}
```

My controller class :-

```
package com.abc.search;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@RestController
public class serviceController {

    @RequestMapping("/suggestMcat/related_info")

    public String getSearchString(HttpServletRequest request){
        JSONObject json;
        json =  new JSONObject(request);
        return json.toString();
    }
    }
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>suggestMcat</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>suggestMcat</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
<relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.json</groupId>
<artifactId>json</artifactId>
<version>20171018</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jazzy/jazzy -->
<dependency>
<groupId>net.sf.jazzy</groupId>
<artifactId>jazzy</artifactId>
<version>0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0</version>
<configuration>
    <outputDirectory>../../tomcat/webapps/</outputDirectory>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
</configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>install-javaml-jar</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <configuration>
            <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/javaml-0.1.6.jar</file>
            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
            <groupId>com.indiamart</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaml</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.6</version>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>install-file</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
        <id>install-ajt-jar</id>
        <phase>clean</phase>
        <configuration>
            <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/ajt-2.11.jar</file>
            <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
            <groupId>com.indiamart</groupId>
            <artifactId>ajt</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
            <generatePom>true</generatePom>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>install-file</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>   
</plugins>
<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

I m getting the below error when i m building the war and deploying on tomcat server:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)
2018-12-04 17:59:39.859  WARN 14727 --- [io-8080-exec-29] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close
     ApplicationContext

         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration]
     from ClassLoader [WebappClassLoader
           context: /suggestMcat
           delegate: false
           repositories:
             /WEB-INF/classes/
         ---------- Parent Classloader:
         java.net.URLClassLoader@3dd4520b
```

Please suggest.

After the answer 2 my issue has been resolved of deploying but the issue is coming with controller
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 04 21:36:49 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Just to note: the spring boot 2 minimum supported version of Tomcat is 8.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you build yourself a war file. You should use spring to do that.

I have full example here https://www.surasint.com/spring-boot-create-war-for-tomcat/

pom.xml should look like this

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.surasint.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-12</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- to deploy as a war in tomcat -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- jstl for jsp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The key point are:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and:

```
<!-- to deploy as a war in tomcat -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: But now issue is coming with routing request:

i m using the below parameter
http://localhost:8080/suggestMcat/related_info?q=bags&source=dev.search

and issue is coming as 
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 04 21:36:49 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: I had added the controller file in the question posted. Please check it once.

Comment: Also.. I m getting the below error
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/validation/ValidationAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean]: Factory method 'defaultValidator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ELManager

Comment: @radhikagarg I suggest you to look in the examples in my website there. Start one by one. And as someone commented, you should use tomcat 8.5. That would help alot.

Answer (score 1):

Your project references the class [`org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/FormContentFilter.html) which resides in spring-web artifact since version 5.1.

So you'll either need to remove the reference to that class or add the missing spring-web artifact.